# Doctrine 2.0 One To Many Schema Validation Problem

Tags: validation, mapping, one-to-many, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

```
class Account
{
...
/*
* @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="account");
*/
private $addresses;
...
}

class Address
{
...
/**
* @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="addresses")
* @JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $account;
...
}
```

When i run console command to validate schema:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Entity\Address' mapping is invalid:
>   * The association Entity\Address#account refers to the inverse side 
>   field Entity\Account#addresses which does not exist

Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the Doctrine annotation reader uses php's Reflection API, specifically `getDocComment` to read the annotations. That means your doc block comments must begin with `/**` otherwise they will be ignored. Your `$addresses` property annotation begins with `/*` so it won't get picked up.

Comment: rojoca i love you man, 3 hours and a *, the problem is solveld, than'k , thank's ..... thank's ,thank's,thank's......